# Invalid JSON Response due to custom wordpress shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress

I've encountered a problem with a custom shortcode i created, which just outputs a table via PHP-Echo.

This shortcode just serves as a search form and posts the data to another site.
Everytime i insert the shortcode in a wp-site and update it, i get "Invalid JSON-Response".

I've tried some troubleshooting and found out that:

The problem just persists with that one shortcode, another custom created shortcode does not error at all. So i guess the problem really "just" lies within the shortcodes-function.

```
<?php

    function function_name() {
        require( WP_PLUGIN_DIR.'/<dir>/assets/runtime/shortcode/function_name/form.php' );
        global $wpdb;
        $filter = $_POST['filter'];
    
        $job_table_name = '<tableName>';
    
        // Check if the Job-Table has Entries
        if ( $wpdb->get_var( 'SELECT * FROM '.$job_table_name ) == null OR $filter == null ) {
            exit;
        }
    
        // Run The Query With Selected Filter
        $query = 'SELECT id, column1, column2, column3 FROM '.$job_table_name." WHERE column1 LIKE '%$filter%' OR id LIKE '$filter'";
        // echo $query;
        $results = $wpdb->get_results( $query, ARRAY_A );
        //echo var_dump( $results );
    
        // Display The Jobs From The Result Set
        echo '<table>';
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<th> column1</th>';
        echo '<th> column2</th>';
        echo '<th> column3</th>';
        foreach ( $results as $result ) {
            echo '<tr>';
            // echo "<td><a href=.site_url().'/displayjobs?id=".$result['column1'].'>'.$result['column2'].'</a></td>';
            ?>
            <td>
            <a href = '<?php echo site_url()?>/displayjobs?id=<?php echo $result["id"]?>'><?php echo $result['column1']?></a></td>
            <?php
            echo '<td>'.$result['column2'].'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$result['column3'].'</td>';
        }
        echo '</table>';
    }

?>
```

Here's the form i'm rendering:

```
<form method='POST'>
  <input type='text' name='filter' placeholder='someval ...'/>
  <input type='submit' value='someval ...'/>
</form>
```

Any ideas on why it fails?

Comment: Can you share form.php file? If you're making a request via ajax in that form, then you should return data in json format

Comment: added to the question!

Comment: Under the comment "// Run The Query With Selected Filter," you appear to have mismatched quotes .... FROM '.$job_table_name." WHERE ....., you see, the second is a double?

Also, it is safer (al less likely to error) if you follow the Placeholders conventions in WP Code Reference: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/#placeholders. Failing to do so can produce unexpected results.

Comment: @JamesValeii: ty for the hint!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've solved the problem myself:

1. I've removed the exit-PHP-Call, which ends the script when the condition is met.
2. I've added `ob_start()` and `ob_get_clean()` to the script

Since I've done that, there are no errors anymore and the plugin can be displayed just fine.

```
<?php

function function_name() {
    global $wpdb;
    $job_table_name = 'someval';
    $num_rows = $wpdb->get_results( 'SELECT COUNT(*) as num_rows FROM '.$job_table_name );
    $filter = $_POST['filter'];

    ob_start();
    require( WP_PLUGIN_DIR.'/someval/assets/runtime/shortcode/form.html' );
    // return ob_get_clean();

    if ( $filter == '' ) {
        $filter = '*';
    }

    // Check if the Job-Table has Entries
    // if ( $wpdb->get_var( 'SELECT * FROM '.$job_table_name ) ) {
    // }

    // Run The Query With Selected Filter
    $query = 'SELECT id, column1, column2, column3 FROM '.$job_table_name." WHERE column2 LIKE '%$filter%' OR id LIKE '$filter'";
    // echo $query;
    $results = $wpdb->get_results( $query, ARRAY_A );
    //echo var_dump( $results );

    // Display The Jobs From The Result Set
    if ( $filter != '' ) {
        // echo 'FILTER: '.$filter;

        echo '<table>';
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<th> column1 </th>';
        echo '<th> column2 </th>';
        echo '<th> column3 </th>';

        foreach ( $results as $result ) {
            echo '<tr>';
            // echo "<td><a href=.site_url().'/somelink?id=".$result['column1'].'>'.$result['column2'].'</a></td>';
            ?>
            <td>
            <a href = '<?php echo site_url()?>/displayjobs?id=<?php echo $result["column1"]?>'><?php echo $result['column2']?></a></td>
            <?php
            echo '<td>'.$result['column3'].'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$result['column4'].'</td>';
        }
    }

    echo '</table>';
    return ob_get_clean();
}

?>
```

Comment: Using output buffer will add a lot of reliability. You no longer need to echo all of the table elements.

Answer (score 0):

Looking good!

So it no longer returns the "invalid JSON response"?

You should consider using $wpdb->prepare and sprintf variables for security. Illustrated below. (I'm not sure on the SQL LIKE wildcards. Codex says "All % characters inside SQL string literals, including LIKE wildcards, must be double-% escaped as %%." ... you'll have to experiment.)

Also, when using output buffer, you can simplify and eliminate some of the 'echo' commands, as illustrated below.

Other updates below:

- error handing/no results output
- if statements to run while counting through each data in each row, in case you want to do something different each time

(Aside from the updates - this is basically your script.)

```
    <?php

    function function_name() {
    global $wpdb;

    $tbl_name = 'someval';
    $num_rows = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare( 'SELECT COUNT(*) as num_rows FROM %s', $tbl_name ) );
    $filter = $_POST['filter'];

    require( WP_PLUGIN_DIR.'/someval/assets/runtime/shortcode/form.html' );

    if ( $filter == '' ) { $filter = '*'; }

    $rows = $wpdb->get_results( 
        $wpdb->prepare( 
            'SELECT id, column1, column2, column3 FROM %s WHERE column2 LIKE "%% %s %%" OR id LIKE "%% %s %%"',
            $tbl_name,
            $filter,
            $filter
        ), ARRAY_A );

    if ( $filter != '' /* && $rows !== ERRORMESSAGE */ ) {
        ob_start(); 
        ?>

        <table>
        <tr>
            <th> column1 </th>
            <th> column2 </th>
            <th> column3 </th>
        </tr>

        <?php 
        $c = 0;
        foreach ( $rows as $row ) { 
            $c++; ?>

            <tr>
                <?php if($c==1): ?>
                    <a href="<?php echo site_url().'/somelink?id='.$row[0]; ?>"><?php echo $row[1]; ?></a>
                <?php elseif($c==2): ?>
                    <span><?php echo $row[2]; ?></span>
                <?php else: ?>
                    <span><?php echo $row[3]; ?></span>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </tr>
        
        <?php } ?>

        </table>
        
    <?php } else { ?>

        <p>Ah, shucks. </p>

    <?php }
    return ob_get_clean();
    }

    ?>
```

Comment: Yes, it does not return the invalid json response! :) Thank you for your help aswell!